# What are config file 2 variables MESIBO_ACCESS_TOKEN & MESIBO_APP_ID

Tags: mesibo

In config.js file , there are following variables.

1. MESIBO_ACCESS_TOKEN
2. MESIBO_APP_ID

I created one user in mesibo console under some ex applicatoin , then added this token for- MESIBO_ACCESS_TOKEN & for MESIBO_APP_ID - App Id which is showing in below screen.

Is it right which I created variables ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MESIBO_ACCESS_TOKEN - is the user token which the user created.

MESIBO_APP_ID - any text ex: test.mesibo.com